# tint2 - short format date?

Tags: linux, date

How to shorten the format of the date

[image]

on this format?

```
09:58 @ nie 20 paź
```

This is the configuration file:

```
#---------------------------------------------
# CLOCK
#---------------------------------------------
time1_format = %H:%M @ %A %d %B
time1_font = Visitor TT1 BRK 10
#time2_format = %A %d %B
time2_font = (null)
clock_font_color = #ffffff 76
clock_padding = 2 1
clock_background_id = 0
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
time1_format = %H:%M @ %a %d %B
time1_font = Visitor TT1 BRK 10
#time2_format = %a %d %B
```

instead of

```
time1_format = %H:%M @ %A %d %B
time1_font = Visitor TT1 BRK 10
#time2_format = %A %d %B
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
%A
```

you can try

```
%a
```

More info with *man date*